# Mongoid - Using object.in(map) as a workaround for has_many :through?

Tags: mongoid, has-many-through, denormalization

I'm converting an AR app into mongoid to learn, and was relying heavily on has_many :through.

```
class User
  has_many comments
  has_many posts, through: :comments
  has_many categories, through :posts
```

This worked for things like retrieving titles of the categories the user posts in most frequently: `user.categories.each`

But with Mongoid not allowing joins, I stumbled across someone elses code for another problem not related to joins, but it seems like it is close to a substitute?

```
def posts 
  Posts.in(id: comments.map(&:post_id))
end
```

I was surprised to see it worked further as well, to the second 'join'

```
def categories
  Category.in(id: user.posts.map(&:category_id)
end
```

It works for my current problem, I just have to call `user.categories.each do` and I have the same functionality as I did with the chained :throughs in AR.

But is this an incorrect way to think about using mongoid? It definitely queries the server multiple times... I've also been learning about denormalizing the data as needed, in this case putting category_ids field directly into users document, but manually updating the data with callbacks seems to get messy, and I haven't been happy with mongoid_denormalize or mongoid_alize gems.

This seems to be a recurring problem for my thought process. For example I'd like to be able to show categories in order of posts.comments.count, or or users who are active in the most popular categoires, or friends of users ordered by those that have the most comments in their posts...

When trying to order_by by second or even third level associations, is there a better way?